# What tools should I use to profile Python code on window 7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, profiling, cprofile

I want to profile python code on Widnows 7. I would like to use something a little more user friendly than the raw dump of cProfile. In that search I found the GUI RunSnakeRun, but I cannot find a way to download RunSnakeRun on Windows. Is it possible to use RunSnakeRun on windows or what other tools could I use?

**Edit:** I have installed RunSnakeRun now. That's progress, thanks guys. How do you run it without a linux command line?

**Edit 2:** I am using this tutorial http://sullivanmatas.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/profiling-python-scripts-with-runsnakerun/ but I hang up at the last line with "python: can't open file 'runsnake.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory "

Comment: Have you tried to `pip install` RunSnakeRun?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget worked fine for me on win7 :)

Comment: Alright, I'll try getting pip and doing that.

Comment: [*There's this method.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771) Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution is to use cProfile (which is in the standard library) and then open the profiles in RunSnakeRun:
http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

cProfile, however only profiles at the per-functions level. If you want line by line profiling try line profiler:
https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Answer (score 1):

I installed runsnake following these [installation instructions](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/).

The step `python runsnake.py profile.pfl` failed because the installation step (`easy_install SquareMap RunSnakeRun`) did not create a file `runsnake.py`.

For me (on Ubuntu), the installation step created an executable at `/usr/local/bin/runsnake`. I figured this out by reading the console output from the installation step. It may be in a different place on Windows, but it should be printed in the output of `easy_install`. To read a profile file, I can execute `/usr/local/bin/runsnake profile.pfl`.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy), written in Rust, safe to use even in production, without modifying any code.

Works on Windows, to install run `pip install py-spy`.

From there you can run `py-spy record -o profile.svg -- python myprogram.py` which produces nice flame graphs.